# Best practice Bootstrap Nav Container width 1400px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

i want to use Bootstrap. But i have the problem, that the Navbar has to be larger then col-lg-12. It is only the nav. The rest is normal. What is best pratice to solve this? The navbar has to be responsive.

regards

Andre

Comment: show your code....if it possible show it using  jsfiddle...

Comment: In the moment i have no code, because i have to start. i found this article:[link](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/06/bootstrap-add-xl-grid-size-option/)

Comment: This will help you..http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Comment: I know how bootstrap works. this was not my question. the large container from bootstrap is 1170px. i need a new container only for the nav who is 1400px. this is my problem how get this work. the rest of the site should have only 1170px as max size. if i change the max size of the container to 1400px then i have the problem that the rest is also 1400px

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I got navbar from the docs and added .container--custom class that will have width=1400 for large devices.

```
 <style>
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .container--custom {
        width: 1400px;
      }
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container container--custom">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```